# Passing Java objects from JSP to an applet

Tags: java, jsp, applet

I created an applet that is called by JSP file. I wish to pass a Java object to the applet. Is it possible, and if it possible how can I do it?

Comment: If it's simply a string object then pass as applet params else set the object in HTTP session as attribute and get back in applet from HTTP session. read [Defining and Using Applet Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/param.html)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389834/applet-server-communication-how-i-can-do-it